# Best way to model selection of a single object in a to-many relationship in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I would like the model the following example in Core Data:

Suppose there are two managed objects, `Owner` and `Item`, where `Owner` has a to-many relationship to a set of `Item`s indicating what `Item`s it owns. `Item` has a one-to-one inverse relationship indicating its `Owner`. In addition, I would like `Owner` to save a reference to a specific `Item` that it is currently selecting/using/etc. Here is what the perfect solution to this situation would include:

1. An `Owner` can access its selected `Item` quickly and conveniently, ideally in the same way it accesses any normal one-to-one relationship.
2. The selected `Item` can only be set to an object in the `Owner`'s list of `Item`s. AKA it is impossible to set the selected `Item` to an `Item` not already owned.
3. `Item`s have their own BOOL property that is always up-to-date and indicates whether or not they are selected by their `Owner`. If it is selected and I want to know the `Owner`, I will just use the other inverse relationship property.
4. In general, keeping everything automatic and up-to-date would be nice, for instance if an `Item` is removed from the owned `Item`s set in `Owner` while it is selected, then it is automatically unselected as well.

I have already tried some limited solutions to this that don't satisfy all my ideal requirements above but do work fine. For example, right now I have two relationships, a to-many relationship indicating all owned `Item`s and a one-to-one relationship linking the currently selected `Item` back to its `Owner`. This works but requires me to be very careful everywhere in my code to make sure things do not become inconsistent. Also, a selected `Item` then has two separate one-to-one relationships back to its `Owner`. This seems like bad design to me because it allows for so many opportunities for the programmer to mess up the relationships if they don't update everything consistently when changes are made.

So my question is whether anyone else has a better solution to this problem? I have more ideas on how I might make this better but none seem convenient to me and I'm wondering if this is a common problem that has been solved already.

Comment: I am currently thinking about the same problem. Are you still using a secondary relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt,

Your problem is probably most easily solved using custom accessors for your selected item. Do you persist the selected state? If not, then a transient one-to-one relationship with custom accessors to enforce your membership constraints will fit the bill nicely. A BOOL is stored as an NSNumber and is not particularly more space efficient, from what I can see, than having the inverse relationship.

Andrew